# Content-Security-Policy (CSP) HTTP Header useful for direct link to image?

Tags: content-security-policy

Is there any reason to show a Content-Security-Policy (CSP) HTTP Header for direct links to images such as `https://invalid.tld/direct-link-to-image.jpeg`?

Comment: The CSP header generally only makes sense for HTML documents, as it specifies what the document will include.

Answer (score 2):

If you are sending the correct type in the `Content-Type` header, the `X-Content-Type-Options` is set to `nosniff` and the image is not in SVG format, CSP shouldn't be necessary. CSP is also not necessary if the content is trusted (i.e. not user-generated) and static.

User-generated SVG is dangerous because the user can upload something like

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" onload="alert('XSS!')"></svg>
```

and send a direct link to another user.

---

However note that although in some cases there is no reason to enable CSP, there is also no reason *not* to enable CSP (other than saving a few bytes). If you accidentally disable CSP for dynamic HTML pages, you can open your website to more XSS attacks.